# Bootstrap header navbar height menu items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I come to you because I'm pulling my hair out of my head on a design issue with bootstrap navbars.

I did a fixed top navbar with differents menu, one on the right and one on the left. 
My CSS code turns the background of my links to the grey when the user hover them. But I notice that my menu items don't have the same height so when my pointer hover the smaller item, the new color doesn't fill the full height of the header bar. 
This is some screenshots to help you :

[image]

[image]

And there is the code of my header bar :

```
<div class="container-fluid header-bar">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Admin Page</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-header -->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li>
      <a href class=" profile_image" >
        <img src="../../../images/user.png" class="img-circle" alt="profile-pic"> {{vm.account.name}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown="">
      <a href class="dropdown-toggle lang_selector" uib-dropdown-toggle="">
        <span class="flag-sm flag-sm-{{vm.defaultLang.flag}}"></span><span class="lang_desc">{{vm.defaultLang.text}}</span> <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu="">
        <li ng-repeat="lang in vm.langs"><a href class="lang_selector" ng-click="vm.defaultLang = lang"><span class="flag-sm flag-sm-{{lang.flag}}"></span><span class="lang_desc">{{lang.text}}</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" ng-click="vm.logout()">
        <md-icon class="li-icon-black material-icons" aria-label="logout">exit_to_app</md-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And there is the CSS code :

```
.smsmode-nav .navbar-header {
     width: 250px;
 }
 .lang_selector > span {
     vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .lang_desc {
    margin-left: 8px
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a.profile_image {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
 .profile_image > img {
    width: 30px;
 }
```

I know there is a story of padding but I try everything and I can't fix it. I'm desperated ! So I need your help please !

Comment: Hi, can you also show us your CSS?

Comment: Actually we need your css here to be sure. But it seems to me as a `line-height` issue and not padding. Set everywhere the line height the same with the height of the bar (or the height you want) and probably this is the issue.

Comment: You can use the same line-height, height and padding values on both links. If that doesn't work, try using overflow:hidden on them.

Comment: Except to set the width of the brand container the CSS used is the Bootstrap default stylesheet ! But i will edit my question with the few CSS I did !

Answer (score 0):

hi remove this css i hope you got your solutions

```
.lang_selector > span {
 vertical-align: middle; 
    }
```